# Handle no internet connection Error in Speech

Tags: ios, error-handling, swift3

I have a UIButton with longPressGestureRecognizer, if user tap and hold the Button, the speech recognition begin, release the button and the spoken text appears in a textField
It works fine, but the Speech Framework from Apple requires valid internet connection. For that reason, I want, that the user get the appropriate message via alert. 
That is the way, I try to handle it my self:

```
 enum InternetConnectionError: Error {
   case noInternet 
   case lowInternetSpeed
 }

 // start the recognition
 @IBAction func longPressAddArticles(_ sender: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
    if sender.state == .began {
        do {
            try startSession()
        } catch  InternetConnectionError.noInternet {
            displayInformationAlert(message: "Sorry, please check your internet connection!")
        } catch InternetConnectionError.lowInternetSpeed {
            displayInformationAlert(message: "Sorry your internet is to slow!")
        // catch All other errors
        } catch let error as Error {
            displayInformationAlert(message: "Unknown error!")
        }
    } else if sender.state == .ended {
        if audioEngine.isRunning {
            audioEngine.stop()
            speechRecognitionRequest?.endAudio()
        }
    }
}

    func displayInformationAlert(message: String) {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Attention", message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel))
    present(alert, animated: true)
}

 private func startSession() throws {
    // check if a previous recognition task is running, and if so cancel it
    if let recognitionTask = speechRecognitionTask {
        recognitionTask.cancel()
        self.speechRecognitionTask = nil
    }

    let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
    try audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryRecord)

    speechRecognitionRequest = SFSpeechAudioBufferRecognitionRequest()

    guard let recognitionRequest = speechRecognitionRequest else {
        throw InternetConnectionError.noInternet
    }

    guard let inputNode = audioEngine.inputNode else {
        throw InternetConnectionError.lowInternetSpeed
    }

    let recordingFormat = inputNode.outputFormat(forBus: 0)
    inputNode.installTap(onBus: 0, bufferSize: 1024, format: recordingFormat) { buffer, _ in
        self.speechRecognitionRequest?.append(buffer)
    }

    audioEngine.prepare()

    do {
        try audioEngine.start()
    } catch {
        displayInformationAlert(message: "The recognition could'n start!")
    }

    speechRecognitionRequest?.shouldReportPartialResults = false
    speechRecognitionTask = speechRecognizer.recognitionTask(with: recognitionRequest) { result, error in
        var finished = false

        if let result = result {
            let articleName = result.bestTranscription.formattedString
            if (self.checkIfShopExists(name:articleName)) {
                self.delegate?.openExistShopWith(name: articleName)
            } else {
                self.createNewArticle(name: articleName)
            }
            finished = result.isFinal
        }

        if error != nil || finished {
            self.audioEngine.stop()
            inputNode.removeTap(onBus: 0)
            self.speechRecognitionRequest = nil
            self.speechRecognitionTask = nil
            self.btnRecordButton.isEnabled = true
        }
    }

}
```

If I turn the iPhone in flight mode, start the app, press the button a lot of times, the app crashes, whithout some helpful crash report

[image]
Some ideas?

Comment: What is your console output?

Comment: That is the point: Nothing.  As you can see in the picture that I post with my question. The app crashes, the AppDelegate appears with "Thread 1: signal SIGABRT"

Comment: That's not the console, click the other panel at the bottom right to show the console.

Comment: Sorry :)

ERROR:    [0x1a86a1b40] >avae> AVAudioNode.mm:565: CreateRecordingTap: required condition is false: _recordingTap == nil
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'com.apple.coreaudio.avfaudio', reason: 'required condition is false: _recordingTap == nil'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x18255efd8 0x180fc0538 0x18255eeac 0x19c5761cc 0x19c5ea57c 0x19c5e817c 0x1000fc630 0x1000f6688 0x1000f6c28 0x188c5fc54 0x188c63488 0x18881d540 0x1886bf45c 0x188c5372c 0x18250c9a0 libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)

Comment: Please edit your question and show relevant code to the error

Answer (score 0):

I use this function to check for internet as the first line of your function. Then just use a guard statement to only proceed if it has internet.

```
func isInternetAvailable() -> Bool
{
    var zeroAddress = sockaddr_in()
    zeroAddress.sin_len = UInt8(MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: zeroAddress))
    zeroAddress.sin_family = sa_family_t(AF_INET)

    let defaultRouteReachability = withUnsafePointer(to: &zeroAddress) {
        $0.withMemoryRebound(to: sockaddr.self, capacity: 1) {zeroSockAddress in
            SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress(nil, zeroSockAddress)
        }
    }

    var flags = SCNetworkReachabilityFlags()
    if !SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags(defaultRouteReachability!, &flags) {
        return false
    }
    let isReachable = (flags.rawValue & UInt32(kSCNetworkFlagsReachable)) != 0
    let needsConnection = (flags.rawValue & UInt32(kSCNetworkFlagsConnectionRequired)) != 0
    return (isReachable && !needsConnection)
}
```